# Is there an implementation of Fast Subset Convolution?

Tags: algorithms

Is there an implementation of the Fast Subset Convolution from this [paper](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rrw/presentations/subset-conv.pdf) available somewhere?

Fast Subset Convolution is used for many dynamic programming FPT algorithms on tree decompositions to achieve better runtimes.

Comment: Requests for implementations of algorithms are off-topic here.

Comment: @Discretelizard Any tip on which SE I could ask this?

Comment: [so] might work. [softwarerecs.se] is another option.